# How to configure AmqpInboundChannelAdapter back off policy

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I want to start my app even if the RabbitMQ is not reachable. Currently my app hangs while AmqpInboundChannelAdapter tries to establish connection and I see pattern how long it waits before it tries again. How to configure app using Spring AMQP to start regardless of RabbitMQ availability and configure this "back off policy"?

18/May/2015 **16:52:57**,666 INFO  [main]  - AmqpInboundChannelAdapter  - started   org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter#0

18/May/2015 **16:54:47**,769 INFO  [main]  - AmqpInboundChannelAdapter  - started org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter#1

18/May/2015 **16:57:07**,818 INFO  [main]  - AmqpInboundChannelAdapter  - started org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter#2

Comment: I'd like to see the whole `DEBUG` log for `org.springframework` category since the start of app and until the connection establishment.